# GSA do not connect to the database that use specal instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, google-search-appliance

We are working on a GSA project. We are using GSA version 7.2 and Connector database adapter 3.2.4. The problem we are facing is that:
- We are crawling data from a MSSQL database 2008 R2. Instance of database is not the default. That is not the instance 'SQLEXPRESS'. And GSA do not connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added JDBC connection URL: DB_HOST_NAME_OR_IP:1433;databaseName=Database Instance Name

Comment: Thanks Manju ! I can do it!